# Fast forward merge on either a branch or merge request specific level

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm aware that in gitlab that it's possible to configure a project to always use fast-forward merges.

**I'm looking to be able to either configure particular branches to always use fast-forward merges, or to choose to do a fast forward merge for a given branch.**

It's possible to do the fast forward merge outside of gitlab, but then the branch would need to be unprotected in order to allow pushes of those changes, which wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

To configure any particular branch to use only fast-forward only , you can use git config command

example :- git config --add mybranch.master.mergeoptions --ff-only

This will allow merge to master from this branch only if its a fast-forward merge

Let me if this answers your query.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, though I'm interested in having gitlab do the fast-forward merging, rather than having it done locally